# User does not have any of the necessary access rights Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, permissions, roles, access-rights, laratrust

I am trying to access dashboard as  super admin
I used laratrust to set roles and permissions:
laratrustSeeder.php file:

```
 <?php

return [
    'role_structure' => [
       'super_admin' => [
            'users' => 'c,r,u,d',
            'categories' => 'c,r,u,d'

        ],
```

databaseSeeder.php:

```
public function run()
{
    // $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
    $this->call([
        LaratrustSeeder::class,
        UsersTableSeeder::class,
    ]);
```

my UsersTableSeeder.php

```
 public function run()
    {
        //

        $user = App\User::create([
            'name'=>'super_admin',
            'email'=>'super_admin@app.com',
            'password'=>bcrypt('123456'),
        ]);

        $user->attachRole('super_admin');
    } //end of run
```

And this is my route:

```
 Route::prefix('dashboard')
->name('dashboard.')
->middleware(['auth','role:super_admin|admin'])
->group(function(){

//make route dashboard.welcome
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('welcome');
//make route categories:
Route::resource('categories','CategoryController')->except(['show']);
Route::resource('roles','RoleController')->except(['show']);

});
```

[image: phpMyadmin DB]

Now I log in uccessfully using super_admin BUT can NOT browse dashboard, I got 403 error:User does not have any of the necessary access rights.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing role in Rote into capital letter: `Super_admin` not `super_admin`.

```
->middleware(['auth','role:Super_admin|admin'])
```

instead of :

```
    ->middleware(['auth','role:super_admin|admin'])
```